# Formatting the display result of a record from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query to get the data I need. I'm trying to display only 10 characters from the left of qQuoteDateTime. However my quotes can't pull down qQuoteDateTime when I put in the left function. Any suggestion or substitute function to be able to display only 10 character of a record?

```
$query = "select left(qQuoteDateTime,10), symSymbol, symExchange, symName, qLastSalePrice, qPreviousClosePrice, qNetChangePrice,qBidPrice, qNetChangePct, qAskPrice, qTodaysHigh, qTodaysLow, q52WeekHigh, q52WeekLow, qShareVolumeQty
from symbols left outer join quotes on quotes.qSymbol = symbols.symSymbol where qSymbol = {$querysymbol} order by qQuoteDateTime desc limit 1";
```

[image: this is my sample out put without the left function]

Comment: Show your sample dataset with your table definitions

Comment: if that is a date, then first convert to a formatted string, then truncate..

Comment: I just attach a picture of the sample data I pull down without the left function. I want to format the date down to just the date, no time. How do I convert it to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
left(qQuoteDateTime,10)
```

Convert the date to a string first, like this:

```
left(CAST(qQuoteDateTime AS CHAR),10)
```

And if you want to give it a convenient name for your PHP results to access this column, add a label to it like this.

```
left(CAST(qQuoteDateTime AS CHAR),10) as qQuoteLeft10
```

Here's a demo:

```
mysql> select LEFT(CAST(NOW() as CHAR),10) as qQuoteLeft10;
+--------------+
| qQuoteLeft10 |
+--------------+
| 2014-06-02   |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

All of the above was written to precisely answer your question.  That said, there's a better way to do it.  Because you're storing the date as a MySQL DateTime type, you're better off getting back exactly what you want using MySQL's native date function.

Here's an example of the better way to get your data back:

```
mysql> select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') as qQuoteLeft10;
+--------------+
| qQuoteLeft10 |
+--------------+
| 2014-06-02   |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

Comment: and then when I extract my data, my variable will be qQuoteLeft10?

Comment: Thanks a lot. And one last question, is DATE_FORMAT a function?